# How can I add a search box to each column

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I'm using kendo gird to create a table.How can I add a search box to each column?

```
  <kendo-grid class="k-grid-p" [data]="gridView" [pageable]="true" [pageSize]="gridState.pageSize"
    (pageChange)="pageChange($event)" [skip]="gridState.state.skip" [sortable]="true" [sort]="gridState.state.sort"
    (sortChange)="sortChange($event)">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `kendoGridHeaderTemplate` to add desired HTML into header:

```
<kendo-grid [data]="yourData">
    <kendo-grid-column field="FirstName">
        <ng-template kendoGridHeaderTemplate let-column let-columnIndex="columnIndex">
             {{column.field}}({{columnIndex}}) 
             <br>
             <input type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
            </ng-template>
        </kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column field="LastName">
        <ng-template kendoGridHeaderTemplate let-column let-columnIndex="columnIndex">
           {{column.field}}({{columnIndex}})
           <br>
           <input type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
        </ng-template>
    </kendo-grid-column>
</kendo-grid>
```

[More information and examples can be seen in Kendo UI for Angular.](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/HeaderTemplateDirective/)